# How do you draw a bar chart in Core Plot where bars extend below the X axis?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I was able to draw a bar chart using the Core Plot framework in my application, but I need to have some of these bars extend below the X axis.  How can I do this in Core Plot?

Comment: @Brad, i am searching a good tutorial to draw Bar chart by use of core-plot can u suggest me any tutorial or blog. Thank you

Comment: @Pooja - Probably the simplest, and most up-to-date, example of a bar chart in Core Plot can be found within the examples provided along with the framework.  Look at the CPTestApp-iPhone example, which has a bar chart as one of its chart types.  It shows how to set up and use such a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the bars negative lengths.

Answer (score 0):

First set negative range for x and y axis like this:

plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-10.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(20.0f)];
   plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-10.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(21.0f)];

Now Set the orthogonal Co-ordinates of x and y axis like this

x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");

Now you can get negative scales.